# How to store phone numbers in MySQL with a universal format

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Phone_Numbers` (
  `ID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `Phone_Number` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  `Date_Modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `Date_Created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  UNIQUE `Main_UK` (`Phone_Number`), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to write into this (either as part of the create or as part of an alter statement) that when the user enters in any of the following:

- (111) 111-1111
- +1 111-111-1111
- 1111111111
- 1 (111) 111-1111

It should universally store any of these values as "1111111111". This should be achievable in the backend of MySQL.

Also, on MS Access, I'm able to put an input mask on my forms which gives me the option to save the data without the input mask characters. Can I enforce an input mask on MySQL, which would be callable from any application, so that the user would be entering it like "(111) 111-1111" and it would be stored as "1111111111"?

Comment: A mask is simply a presentational way of displaying your numbers: ideally you should not be storing phone numbers in a format: just the digits themselves should be sufficient. Then, you can store a mask/formatter alongside the number: perhaps the region/country is sufficient for you to decide on how should the number be displayed on screen.

Comment: @Terry Yes. How do I achieve that in MySQL? What do I have to write in my CREATE statement to enforce that?